# Multiple ajax call send when user submit popup form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup

In my application, there is a jQuery popup window where I am listing suppliers along with the checkbox in front of each supplier. Then the user can check one of the checkboxes at each supplier and press delete button to delete a supplier. However, once the user clicks the delete button, ajax call correctly sends to the server side and delete the supplier properly at the server side (deleted supplier no longer displays in the list). Once user did same again, I noticed that popup window send two ajax request to the server side. If the user clicks third time, popup window sends ajax request three times, so on.

```
var ajaxURL = getFormAction('crm.web.SupplierManager', 
'deleteSupplierRequestAjax');
$("#deleteBtnId").click(function( event ) {
    $( "#supplierDeleteConfirmDivId" ).dialog( "open" );
    $( "#supplierPopupCancelBtnId" ).click(function( event ) {
    $( "#supplierDeleteConfirmDivId" ).dialog( "close" );
    event.preventDefault();
});
$( "#supplierPopupOkBtnId" ).click(function( event ) {
    $( "#supplierDeleteConfirmDivId" ).dialog( "close" );
        $("#supplierPopupOkBtnId").mask("Waiting...");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#formId").serialize(),
            url: ajaxURL,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#supplierPopupOkBtnId").html(data);
                $("#supplierPopupOkBtnId").unmask();
            },
            error: function(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#supplierPopupOkBtnId").unmask();
                handleAjaxError(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
event.preventDefault();
});
```

For me, it seems like form, rendering accumulate into the popup window each time user click the delete button. I am not sure it is the real reason. I am guessing `$("#formId").serialize()` make the trouble. Anyone has different idea?

Comment: Can try using  async: false,

Comment: Don't use `async: false`, it's deprecated. If you need asynchronous code, see `Promises`.

Comment: Thank you @Zenoo Any idea how this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With:

```
$( "#supplierPopupCancelBtnId" ).click(function( event ){})
```

You are creating every time a new listener on button, this is cumulative.

Try with "one":

```
$( "#supplierPopupCancelBtnId" ).one( "click", function() {});
```

From jquery docs:

"The .one() method is identical to .on(), except that the handler for a given element and event type is unbound after its first invocation."

Comment: Applied your suggestion. Yes..!!, you are correct. it is working correctly. Thank you..!!!